# How to do two Lorentzian fit

Tags: fitting

```
xx = Import["avgug.xlsx"]
Show[
 ListLinePlot[xx, 
  PlotRange -> {{0.5, 4.5}, {60, 270}}, 
  PlotStyle -> {{AbsoluteThickness[3]}},  
  BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 18},  
  FrameLabel -> {"q (nm)", "intensity (a.u)"}, 
  PlotRangePadding -> 0.05
  ], 
 Frame -> True, 
 PlotLabel -> HoldForm[intensity vs q], 
 LabelStyle -> {18, GrayLevel[0]}, 
 ImageSize -> 800
 ]
```

Data can be downloaded [from here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1MqxkADEARiYyTXX9AeR_ERSv4Wc98prC).

I tried to use lorentzianfit but I could not make it. Is it possible that all initial values can be selected automatically? Also I want to know FWHM and peak position after fitting.

Comment: Could you show what you tried?  I don't have `lorentzianfit` on my version of *Mathematica*.  Could you also state what FWHM and peak position means?  You'll get a lot more and better help if you give necessary details.

Comment: FWHM means full width half maxima, after fit where is the highest point is called peak point. Actually loentzianfit is not building function of Mathematica, it is kind of non liner fit. I used  y= y0 + (2A/PI) w/{(x-xc)^2 + w^2}, where A is area, xc is the peak position on x axis, w width of peak

Comment: Down-voting because your question is not clear. Define "Lorentzian fit" or provide links to it. Define what you understand under "FWHM".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is more of an extended comment in that it performs the fit you weren't able to get to work but the chosen function does not fit the data well.

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, y0 + (2 a/Pi) w/{(x - xc)^2 + w^2},
  {{y0, 50}, a, w, xc}, x];
nlm["BestFitParameters"]
(* {y0 -> 94.8605, a -> 154.98, w -> 0.588704, xc -> 3.06449} *)

Show[ListPlot[data, Joined -> True, PlotLegends -> {"Data"}],
 Plot[nlm[x], {x, Min[data[[All, 1]]], Max[data[[All, 1]]]}, 
  PlotStyle -> Red, PlotLegends -> {"Fit"}]]
```

[image: Lorentzian fit with data]

Comment: Thank you @JimB, it is really helpful. As you see there should be two Lorenzian fit. Can you please do it for both peak

Comment: There should be enough here for you to try a more complicated model.  (And I see 3 peaks (in the sense that the lack of fit in the right tail won't be any better with 2 peaks.)